# Inclusivity of Julia ranges

Tags: julia

I hate that ranges include the end. Here is an example where I've deliberately removed the end of the range.

```
N = 100
for x in 0.0 : 2*pi/N : 2*pi*(N-1)/N
    println(x)
end
```

Is there any way to avoid the ugliness of this for loop?

Comment: Exclusive ends make sense for continuous sets, like the Reals, but it does not make sense at all for discrete and finite sets, like the one you are asking about. It is an unfortunate mistake by Python/C++ et al. I do understand why you want it in this case, but it is a bad idea as a general design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, inclusive ranges (and 1-based indexing) is baked into the idioms of Julia at a fundamental level.

However, for this specific case, do note that stepping with floating point values can be problematic, as adding N values might be less than, equal to, or greater than the final value, giving different results for the for loop.  Although julia [tries](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2333) [really hard](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/33677), there's no way to quite do the right thing in all circumstances.  As a bonus, working in integer values only for the ranges simplifies things.  You might want to consider:

```
for ix in 0:N-1
    x = ix * 2 * pi / N
    println(x)
end
```

Alternatively, the `range()` function has a form with a `len` parameter:

```
for x in range(0, 2*pi*(N-1)/N, length=n)
    println(x)
end
```

Or indeed, combining this with the other answer of only taking (N-1) could work.

Comment: These are good suggestions, especially the point about floating point ranges. I ran into this problem myself for the case mentioned above.

Comment: @Alex: the suggestion by Stepan Zakharov, using the step= keyword is better.  It still avoids the floating point issues as the length is stepped directly, while using only addition for the steps, and unlike my second alternative, skips the ugly multiplying by (N-1)/N, just to undo it inside the range call.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is

```
N = 100
for x in range(0; step=2π/N, length=N)
    println(x)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the most elegant way... take the first n-1 elements

```
r = 0.0 : 2*pi/N : 2*pi
r = Iterators.take(r,length(r)-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could actually define your own operator such as:

```
▷(a,b) = a:b-1
```

Now you can write:

```
julia> 3▷6
3:5
```

Julia also natively supports custom indices for arrays. There is a package `CustomUnitRanges` that is maybe an overkill here.